# node tar without parent directories

Tags: node.js, directory, tar

I use tar in node and would like to compress a folder without its parent directories.
The archive is being created but including all folders of the absolute path.

How do I specify the cwd correctly, which should change into the directory I want and only compress the folder 'archive'?

```
tar.create(
        {
            cwd: '/var/folders/fy/8xtt5hmn4_db7rc0b4rkvd2h0000gp/T',
            noDirRecurse: true,
            file: '/var/folders/fy/8xtt5hmn4_db7rc0b4rkvd2h0000gp/T/archive.tgz'
        },
        ['/var/folders/fy/8xtt5hmn4_db7rc0b4rkvd2h0000gp/T/archive']
    ).then(_ => { functions.logger.log('tgz file created'); })
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to delete the path from the original folder:

```
tar.create(
    {
        cwd: '/var/folders/fy/8xtt5hmn4_db7rc0b4rkvd2h0000gp/T',
        file: '/var/folders/fy/8xtt5hmn4_db7rc0b4rkvd2h0000gp/T/archive.tgz'
    },
    ['archive']
).then(_ => { functions.logger.log('tgz file created'); })
```